# Websockets, fragmentation and available data through recv

Tags: c, sockets, websocket

I'm building a websocket server. To parse the frames, I'm doing something like:

```
// first fetch the first 2 bytes
result = recv(socket_fd, header_buffer, 2, 0);
```

where 2 is the length that I need to fetch for the header. Then parse it and keep fetching as such:

```
// fetch extended payload length - 2 or 8
result = recv(socket_fd, header_extended_buffer, extended, 0);

// fetch masking key, 4
result = recv(socket_fd, header_masking_key_buffer, 4, 0);

// fetch payload
result = recv(socket_fd, payload_buffer, payload_size, 0);
```

Question, is it possible that this won't always work? I'm aware that `recv` could fetch only the first byte and when data becomes available, it will send some extra bytes.

Do I need to keep track of this and concatenate to each of the different buffers as data becomes available under recv? Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to keep track of this and concatenate to each of the
>   different buffers as data becomes available under recv?

Yes.

I would use a byte-by-byte state-machine, but maybe that's just me....

Comment: That confirms my concern. Thanks.